# Android Studio console won't let me enter input to Scanner

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, java.util.scanner

I am writing a plain old java program in Android Studio:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
int count = input.nextInt();
```

console:

```
3:51:55 AM: Executing task 'Main.main()'...

Executing tasks: [Main.main()] in project C:\Users\pengj\AndroidStudioProjects\276A1

> Task :plainOldJava:compileJava
> Task :plainOldJava:processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :plainOldJava:classes

> Task :plainOldJava:Main.main() FAILED
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
    at cmpt276.a1.plainoldjava.Main.main(Main.java:19)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':plainOldJava:Main.main()'.
> Process 'command 'C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/jre/bin/java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
Enter an integer: 
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.6.4/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 279ms
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
3:51:55 AM: Task execution finished 'Main.main()'.
```

The same codes work in IntelliJ, which Android Studio is based on, that makes me very confused.

Comment: Use EditText for getting user input.